# Installation of zf2 on LAMP in kali linux?

Tags: php, linux, apache, zend-framework2, xampp

I tried a lot to run directly through `zend.localhost` and and got frustrated 
I am using `xammp` in `kali linux`
but it shows as in pic
I had added this in my `httpd-vhost.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zend.localhost
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/zend/public

    <Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/zend/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

We will need a little more explanation on your error to help you ...

Did you mapped zend.localhost to `127.0.0.1` (or your ip address) in your `/etc/hosts` ?